# Installing Windows Service with SC

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am installing some services with the `installutils` command but I'm having immense trouble in getting these to install using the `SC create` command. What is the difference between the two modes. I'm getting no error from the command, but a series of options. Here is the format I am using:

```
SC create ZAM displayname= "ZAM" binpath="E:\ZAM\ZAM.exe" start=auto
```

and I get the following:

```
DESCRIPTION:
        Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
USAGE:
        sc <server> create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...

OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
      A space is required between the equal sign and the value.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec>
       (default = own)
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto>
       (default = demand)
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
       (default = normal)
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
       (default = LocalSystem)
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```

I don't understand what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is frequent. ALL parameters in sc command with an equal sign in them must have the same format:

```
parameter=<SPACE>value
```

As is. Space is required

Comment: Is there also a way to incorporate username and password? I don't see this as an option to do it?

Comment: see `sc create /? ` parameters are `obj=` and `password=`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of calling 'sc' directly, I recommend using [`New-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849830.aspx). The parameters are a direct translation. It is available in the default powershell modules.